# URL-based single page app nav in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application, html5-history

I'm trying to write a single-page web app in JavaScript. Desired behavior:

- When the user goes to `http://myapp.example.com` (the main page), or any other URL off of that domain for the first time, their browser downloads 1 large HTML file (and associated JS/CSS/image files, etc.). --> **so big upfront download**
- The HTML file contains `<div>` elements that each represent a different "page"; only 1 "page" div will be displayed at any given time
- When the user clicks a link that should bring them to a different "page", JS manipulates the DOM to hide the current page and show/display the desired one
- Every time the user "navigates" to a different "page", the URL in their browser should change, and the new URL should be added to browser history via HTML5 History API

I'm wondering how to do this. I'd greatly prefer something jQuery-based rather than trying to write something homegrown. But if I have to write this code myself, then given the following general structure of the 1 HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head> ... </head>
    <body>
        <div id="home" class="page">
            <!-- Content for home page, say http://myapp.example.com/#home. -->
        </div>

        <div id="about" class="page">
            <!-- Content for About page, say http://myapp.example.com/#about. -->
        </div>

        <div id="contact" class="page">
            <!-- Content for Contact page, say http://myapp.example.com/#contact. -->
        </div>

        <!-- Etc. for all other "pages" -->         
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I:

- Hide all "page divs" by default, and then inspect the URL to figure out which "page" to show/display?
- Add the current URL to the browser history via the HTML5 History API?

Comment: If you're using the history API, then the default state of the app should be set up by the server.

Comment: Do you have to use jQuery? Cause I think thats a more scalable and maintainable if you did it with [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) using routes

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Where are your own tries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use and set the `window.location.hash` and use that value to `$("#yourDivId").show()` and `$("#yourDivId").hide()` your divs.

On the `onload` you can `$("#yourDivId").show()` the requested (or default if none was requested) div, and `$("#yourDivId").hide()` the other divs.

And on each link, either directly change the hash and set the requested div visible. Or set a timer that checks the hash on an interval to see if the hash has changed. (There is no native onhashchange event.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should hide every div at start.

```
$(div#page).hide();
```

Then, you can check the current URl by using:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

Every time the user changes the URL: first hide every div, then check and show the desired div.

Comment: Instead of $(div#page).hide(); I guess you can do: $(#page).each(function(t){t.hide();});

Answer (score 0):

That is the reason of Single Page Application Framework's existence. I think it does worth learning some of the, such as AngularJS or BackboneJS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abuse the browser history, I suggest you read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) on `history.pushState()`. **:-)**